# How can we make password creation rule for Mongodb user?

Tags: mongodb

I wanted to create some predefined rules for password  when the admin user create users in Mongodb. is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB does offer schema validation since version 3.2. See: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/schema-validation/

I'm not sure what programming language you are using, but if you are using Node.js you might consider using Mongoose as the validation rules might be more flexible for your use cases. See: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html

Comment: you explained about document level schema validation. doesn't make any sense with user password creation validation. actually i want the feature when  i create a user via mongos shell.